# Android - NavigationDrawer (Slide Bar меню), структура программы

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток. Накопал на stackoverflow ссылку на [NavigationDrawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) меню, почитал, прилепил в свое приложение. В коде я при клике на элемент списка меню нашел код (в самом низу страницы лежит полный код MainActivity) и вот что озадачило:

```
case 0:  
    fragment = new HomeFragment();  
    break;  
case 1:  
    fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();  
    break;
```

продолжение в то же духе. Так вот, при клике на элемент, на экран приложения выводится фрагмент соответствующего элемента списка. Какой же тогда станет структура программы? Т.е. везде будут фрагменты? Можно ли как-то обойтись без этих фрагментов, чтобы при клике на элемент списка создавать новое Activity с нужным содержимым?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Можно ли как-то обойтись без этих фрагментов, чтобы при клике на элемент списка создавать новое Activity с нужным содержимым?

Эмммм а зачем ?  NavigationDrawer  предполагает использование фрагментов, без них не добится той скорости работы, да и удобнее на порядок

Comment: да и удобнее на порядок

А если у меня есть разделы, штук 15, в каждом есть x категорий. Разве будет удобно создавать 15*x фрагментов и столько же layout'ов?

Comment: определенно удобнее ─ боковое меню само по себе фрагмент, вешать на него можно любые слушатели и обрабатывать как вам больше нравится, хотя использовать activity ля этого будет довольно таки извратно. Никто не заставляет создавать все 15*x фрагментов единовременно, если все фрагменты разной структуры то разные  разметки все равно создавать придется, activity это не решит ) Если фрагменты одинаковой структуры, но с разными данными то просто передавайте туда эти данные.

Comment: Я от себя добавлю. Фрагменты удобнее от Activity хотя бы тем, что их не нужно прописывать в Манифесте. В остальном их жизненный цикл очень сходный. Так что проще сделать родительский Activity, на котором будут отображаться фрагменты и работать с ними.

Comment: + ко всем радостям  фрагментов можно запретить пересоздавать Activity при повороте и  пересоздовать только фрагмент, если логика в Activity  то это упрощает работу, мелочь а приятно, да и работает быстрее